# android client-server data synchronization with offline mode

Tags: android, client-server, offline

I'm trying to implement client-server application for android tablet with offline mode.
Current usage scenario:

1. Get updates by “changed” timestamp
2. Open an entity
3. make changes, get some photos
4. save changes to  local SQLite (except photos)
5. send changes to server (if not offline) and get updates.

It works nice with single client and stable wifi, but with 2 or more clients some changes missing on editing the same entry. Also, there is no Internet connection on client and server, so i can’t use GCM or online sync services.

So, the questions are:

1. Is there complete solutions for data synchronization with offline feature (frameworks, libraries)?
2. How to merge changes if two or more clients editing the same data? 
   I think for some kind of “EntityLocked” table for preventing editing while clients online, but not sure about offline changes handling.
3. How to ensure data synced with server?
4. Any suggestions for data sync priority? ( for example, critical data syncing first, photos uploading later)
5. Which technology\library is good for server push? For now, i’m using mqtt for notifying clients.

Comment: this is too broad, you should split these up in 3 or 4 different questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. The questions are interesting, but you are asking too much.